# Acronym Nested Parentheses

Tags: acronyms, nesting

This question is mainly to collect your opinion, and probably to reach a good solution. That said, let's go to the discussion topic and question.

I commonly use the `acronym` package in my work, mainly to write article with lots of abbreviations. Sometimes I also use `glossaries` for the same purpose. I know there are others.

Well, when using those, it sometime may happen that an acronym is expanded inside parentheses, e.g.,

> the \ac{BS} (also known as \ac{eNB})

become

> the Base Station (BS) (also known as Enhanced Node B (eNB))

As it may be seen, in the second expansion, it get nested parentheses. To avoid this, I sometimes use `\acs{}` instead of `\ac{}` while inside parentheses. However, it may happen that the acronym is first used inside the parentheses, and with this approach it is not expanded in the first use.

I was reading [link 1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11155/is-it-acceptable-to-nest-parentheses) and [link 2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28195/double-parentheses), and while people said it is acceptable, others recommend to rephase, or use brackets. With brackets, my simple example would become

> the Base Station (BS) (also known as Enhanced Node B [eNB])

A solution for this, would be use always brackets instead of parentheses while using acronyms. But I don't know if it is acceptable of all purposes or not.

What is your opinion?

Further, is it possible to say to `acronym` or other package to use brackets inside parentheses?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
  \acro{BS}{Base Station}
  \acro{eNB}{Enhanced Node B}
\end{acronym}

the \ac{BS} (also known as \ac{eNB})

\end{document}
```

Comment: `The \ac{BS}, also known as \ac{eNB}, ...`

Comment: @egreg I know that I can most of the times re-work the text. This is just a simple example. But possibly there are others, where it is better to keep parentheses.

Comment: You can set the acronym as used even if you use `\acs{<label>}` by calling `\acused{<label>}`. That's what I've been doing as a workaround in general. You can probably put those two in a macro if you want to save some keypresses.

Comment: That is a possible solution. But as I said in the post, if it is the first time, the acronym is not expanded. The problem become worst if you are in a paper because you should use `nolist` option to the package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't help with the `acronym` package as I don't use it, but if you don't mind using `glossaries` instead you can do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries}

\newacronym{bs}{BS}{Base Station}
\newacronym{enb}{eNB}{Enhanced Node B}

\newcommand*{\pac}[2][]{\ifglsused{#2}{\acs[#1]{#2}}{%
 \glsunset{#2}%
 \acl[#1]{#2} [\acs[#1]{#2}]}}

\begin{document}

\ac{bs} (also known as \pac{enb}).

Later: \ac{bs} (also \pac{enb})

\end{document}
```

Here you can just use `\pac` instead of `\ac` when you want to use the acronym in parentheses.

Result:

[image: Image of resulting text]

An alternative approach (which most may consider overkill) is to do:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortcuts]{glossaries}

\newcount\parencount
\DeclareRobustCommand{\openparen}{\global\advance\parencount by 1\relax
\ifodd\parencount(\else[\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\closeparen}{\ifodd\parencount)\else]\fi
 \global\advance\parencount by -1\relax
}

\catcode`\(=\active
\catcode`\)=\active

\let(\openparen
\let)\closeparen

\renewcommand{\acrfullformat}[2]{#1\space\noexpand\openparen#2\noexpand\closeparen}

\newacronym{bs}{BS}{Base Station}
\newacronym{enb}{eNB}{Enhanced Node B}

\begin{document}

Some parenthesis: (outer level (inner level (getting silly))).

\ac{bs} (also known as \ac{enb}).

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of resulting text]

**Edit:** Caveat: it's best not to use the second approach if you use a package such as `tikz` where parentheses form part of the command syntax.

**Edit:** Here's an example that switches back and forth, which can either be done by changing the category codes of `(` and `)` or changing their definition:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\orgopenparen(
\let\orgcloseparen)

\newcount\parencount
\DeclareRobustCommand{\openparen}{\global\advance\parencount by 1\relax 
\ifodd\parencount(\else[\fi}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\closeparen}{\ifodd\parencount)\else]\fi
 \global\advance\parencount by -1\relax
}

\catcode`\(=\active
\catcode`\)=\active

\let(\openparen
\let)\closeparen

\begin{document}

Some parenthesis: (outer level (inner level (getting silly))).

% restore original behaviour (changing definition)
\let(\orgopenparen
\let)\orgcloseparen

Some parenthesis: (outer level (inner level (getting silly))).

% switch back

\let(\openparen
\let)\closeparen

Some parenthesis: (outer level (inner level (getting silly))).

% restore original behaviour (changing category code)
\catcode`\(=12\relax
\catcode`\)=12\relax

Some parenthesis: (outer level (inner level (getting silly))).

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Image of resulting text]

Comment: Your solution seems very good. I will try it later. It seems to do what I was checking. I think it can be an be an improvement for `glossaries` or `acronym` packages

Comment: The latest solution does work with `acronym` if it is loaded before that package. Is it possible in the latest solution get the normal meaning of `()` after using a command like `\ac{}`? Something like: 1. save previous meaning; 2. refine meaning in nested mode; 3. use acronym command; 4. restore saved meaning.

Comment: @cacamailg I've added an extra example that shows you how to restore the meaning of `(` and `)`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew that to restore the meaning was something like you did, but I couldn't figure out the `catcode`.

Answer (score 0):

As to the OP's question:

> Further, is it possible to say to acronym or other package to use brackets inside parentheses?

Yes, it is. For `acronym` package, simply use:

```
\acrodef{eNB}[{[}eNB{]}]{Enhanced Node B}
```

Notice that you have to escape the square brackets by putting each inside `{}`.